# Values aren't being passed from one controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

Passing data between two separate controllers. I have the following in my first file:

```
public ActionResult Report(string sDate, string eDate)
{   
    var client = new WebClient();
    string avgRatesCos = String.Format(client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/values/1?sBookingDate={0}&eBookingDate={1}"), sDate, eDate);
    string maxAvgRates = String.Format(client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/values/2?sBookingDate={0}&eBookingDate={1}"), sDate, eDate);
    string minAvgRates = String.Format(client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/values/3?sBookingDate={0}&eBookingDate={1}"), sDate, eDate);
```

in my second file/controller my values in 'sBookingDate' and 'eBookingDate' show up as {0} and {1} instead of values being passed from the first controller:

```
public QueryResponse Get(int id, string sBookingDate, string eBookingDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sBookingDate, eBookingDate);
}
```

Comment: `&` || `&&` ?not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `String.Format` and your `client.DownloadString` operations backwards. So you're literally just requesting the {0} as the parameter... then calling `String.Format` on the result of the call to the action/controller.

Instead of

```
string avgRatesCos = String.Format(client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/values/1?sBookingDate={0}&eBookingDate={1}"), sDate, eDate);
```

it should be

```
string avgRatesCos = client.DownloadString(String.Format("http://localhost/api/values/1?sBookingDate={0}&eBookingDate={1}", sDate, eDate));
```

Comment: You beautiful SOB! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string minAvgRates = client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/values/3?sBookingDate=" +sDate + "&eBookingDate="+eDate);
```